# WiFi was working fine until battery died, now says no wifi adapter found

Tags: networking, battery

I have a chuwi herobook Pro laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed. It has been working fine for months but last night the battery died unfortunately and now there is no WiFi connection.

The WiFi options simply did not appear in the top task bar or normal settings menu. By searching WiFi in applications I have found the WiFi setting but simply have a screen that says "no WiFi adapter found" with no options to change anything.

I can ping an receive proper response from local host.

Is it possible the battery dying turned wifi adapters off somehow to try and save power?

There is no ethernet port on the laptop so I cannot test with a cable.

I cannot find similar problems anywhere, since the WiFi adapters were all working fine up until this point when the laptop shot down due to no power.

Thank you

dit: thank you to everyone trying to help, its really appreciated. Here are my efforts to the suggestions:

1/ the guide asked me to run lshw  - C network,  this required suoer-user permission so I ran with sudo at he front of the command. The word 'usb' appeared temporarily before disappearing and returning me to normal command line. Not sure where to go from there.

However, from another guide I did get a list of adapters which I think was the aim and there was no relevant adapter in the list. I will try to find the exact command I used and edit again with the full results.

2/ the aeroplane toggle switch is not appearing where it should. The settings menu that usually had a section for WiFi is not there, but if I type WiFi into applications it takes me back to the settings screen and now has the WiFi tab, but unfortunately the screen has no interactivity just a message saying "no WiFi adapter found. Make sure you have a WiFi adapter plugged in and turned on". After your suggestion I tried two other commands: sudo rfkill block all and nmcli nm wifi off, but neither had any effect.

3/ the lspci - vvnn etc command (sorry for not typing out in full on mobile) didn't print anything to screen, it had no reaction when entered into terminal at all.

2 extra notes:
-it appears Bluetooth is also disabled, the settings menu still has the Bluetooth tab but simple says "no blue tooth found. Plug in a dingle to use Bluetooth" - the toggle in the top bar cannot be used. I have never used a dingle before or a external wireless adapter, it seems like these connectivity settings have been disabled somehow..

-I do have a Windows partition (but haven't booted windows for 2 months),  on there the connectivity is also down and it appears to find no wireless adapters either.

Thank you

Comment: Does [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en) solve your problem?? Link: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en

Comment: Have you tried turning airplane mode on and off? Thanks.

Comment: First thing, look for a keyboard shortcut, most laptops have this, even guggle it for your model. Second, open a terminal and type `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` and add the output to your question above (edit your question).

Comment: I have added information to the original post after following all the suggestions in replies. Tja k you for your help but I am still stuck at the moment.

Comment: The comment above suggested a **keyboard shortcut** which Chuwi laptops have, usually FN + some F key. That should be the first thing to try. If it doesn't enable the WiFi (and BT) then look for a setting in UEFI that might have been disabled. If nothing there and nothing else works try a live session just in case. If the device isn't showing up after all this checks then the conclusion is it's defective. Unfortunately, like most "slimbooks" the WiFi is probably not replaceable (soldered on the motherboard).

Comment: The keyboard shortcut appears to have no effect at all. In Windows (just because I followed a few troubleshooting guides for Windows) I went into the network devices and again a wireless adapter just doesn't appear so it does seem like it's gone defective somehow.  What do you mean by a live session?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the wireless adapter and bluetooth adapter componnts had been completely removed temporarily.

It seems to be a windows thing as other people have experienced it, even though I haven't booted the windows partition in months. The components were completely gone from the device manager in windows and couldn't be seen through the command queires in linux (it just said they didnt exist).

But, as per other windows users experiences, after letting it charge fully, rebooting several times and waiting a few hours one of the reboots eventually started up with working connections and the components appeared again (it was on a ubuntu boot it that it magically started working).

THanks to everyone that tried to help me.